# Optimizing LINQ routines

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, linq, entity-framework

I run a build system. Datawise the simplified description would be that I have Configurations and each config has 0..n Builds. 
Now builds produce artifacts and some of these are stored on server. What I am doing is writing kind of a rule, that sums all the bytes produced per configuration builds and checks if these are too much.

The code for the routine at the moment is following:

```
private void CalculateExtendedDiskUsage(IEnumerable<Configuration> allConfigurations)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    // Lets take only confs that have been updated within last 7 days
    var items = allConfigurations.AsParallel().Where(x =>
        x.artifact_cleanup_type != null && x.build_cleanup_type != null &&
        x.updated_date > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7)
        ).ToList();

    using (var ctx = new LocalEntities())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Context: " + sw.Elapsed);
        var allBuilds = ctx.Builds;
        var ruleResult = new List<Notification>();
        foreach (var configuration in items)
        {
            // all builds for current configuration
            var configurationBuilds = allBuilds.Where(x => x.configuration_id == configuration.configuration_id)
                .OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
            Debug.WriteLine("Filter conf builds: " + sw.Elapsed);

            // Since I don't know which builds/artifacts have been cleaned up, calculate it manually
            if (configuration.build_cleanup_count != null)
            {
                var buildCleanupCount = "30"; // default
                if (configuration.build_cleanup_type.Equals("ReserveBuildsByDays"))
                {
                    var buildLastCleanupDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-int.Parse(buildCleanupCount));
                    configurationBuilds = configurationBuilds.Where(x => x.build_date > buildLastCleanupDate)
                            .OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
                }
                if (configuration.build_cleanup_type.Equals("ReserveBuildsByCount"))
                {
                    var buildLastCleanupCount = int.Parse(buildCleanupCount);
                    configurationBuilds =
                        configurationBuilds.Take(buildLastCleanupCount).OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
                }
            }

            if (configuration.artifact_cleanup_count != null)
            {
                // skipped, similar to previous block
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Done cleanup: " + sw.Elapsed);
            const int maxDiscAllocationPerConfiguration = 1000000000; // 1GB
            // Sum all disc usage per configuration
            var confDiscSizePerConfiguration = configurationBuilds
                .GroupBy(c => new {c.configuration_id})
                .Where(c => (c.Sum(z => z.artifact_dir_size) > maxDiscAllocationPerConfiguration))
                .Select(groupedBuilds =>
                    new
                    {
                        configurationId = groupedBuilds.FirstOrDefault().configuration_id,
                        configurationPath = groupedBuilds.FirstOrDefault().configuration_path,
                        Total = groupedBuilds.Sum(c => c.artifact_dir_size),
                        Average = groupedBuilds.Average(c => c.artifact_dir_size)
                    }).ToList();
            Debug.WriteLine("Done db query: " + sw.Elapsed);

            ruleResult.AddRange(confDiscSizePerConfiguration.Select(iter => new Notification
            {
                ConfigurationId = iter.configurationId,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                RuleType = (int) RulesEnum.TooMuchDisc,
                ConfigrationPath = iter.configurationPath
            }));
            Debug.WriteLine("Finished loop: " + sw.Elapsed);
        }
        // find owners and insert...
    }
}
```

This does exactly what I want, but I am thinking if I could make it any faster. Currenly I see:

```
Context: 00:00:00.0609067
// first round
Filter conf builds: 00:00:00.0636291
Done cleanup: 00:00:00.0644505
Done db query: 00:00:00.3050122
Finished loop: 00:00:00.3062711
// avg round
Filter conf builds: 00:00:00.0001707
Done cleanup: 00:00:00.0006343
Done db query: 00:00:00.0760567
Finished loop: 00:00:00.0773370
```

The `SQL` generated by `.ToList()` [looks very messy.](http://pastebin.com/RHFDYKtk) (Everything that is used in `WHERE` is covered with an index in DB)

I am testing with 200 configurations, so this adds up to 00:00:18.6326722. I have a total of ~8k items that need to get processed daily (so the whole routine takes more than 10 minutes to complete).

I have been randomly googling around this internet and it seems to me that `Entitiy Framework` is not very good with parallel processing. Knowing that I still decided to give this `async/await` approch a try (First time a tried it, so sorry for any nonsense).

Basically if I move all the processing out of scope like:

```
foreach (var configuration in items)
    {

        var confDiscSizePerConfiguration = await GetData(configuration, allBuilds);

        ruleResult.AddRange(confDiscSizePerConfiguration.Select(iter => new Notification
        {
           ... skiped
    }
```

And:

```
private async Task<List<Tmp>> GetData(Configuration configuration, IQueryable<Build> allBuilds)  
{
        var configurationBuilds = allBuilds.Where(x => x.configuration_id == configuration.configuration_id)
            .OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
        //..skipped
        var confDiscSizePerConfiguration = configurationBuilds
            .GroupBy(c => new {c.configuration_id})
            .Where(c => (c.Sum(z => z.artifact_dir_size) > maxDiscAllocationPerConfiguration))
            .Select(groupedBuilds =>
                new Tmp
                {
                    ConfigurationId = groupedBuilds.FirstOrDefault().configuration_id,
                    ConfigurationPath = groupedBuilds.FirstOrDefault().configuration_path,
                    Total = groupedBuilds.Sum(c => c.artifact_dir_size),
                    Average = groupedBuilds.Average(c => c.artifact_dir_size)
                }).ToListAsync();
        return await confDiscSizePerConfiguration;
    }
```

This, for some reason, drops the execution time for 200 items from 18 -> 13 sec. Anyway, from what I understand, since I am `await`ing each `.ToListAsync()`, it is still processed in sequence, is that correct?

So the "can't process in parallel" claim starts coming out when I replace the `foreach (var configuration in items)` with `Parallel.ForEach(items, async configuration =>`. Doing this change results in:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

It was a bit confusing to me at first as I `await` practically in every place where the compiler allows it, but possibly the data gets seeded to fast.

I tried to overcome this by being less greedy and added the `new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4}` to that parallel loop, peasant assumption was that default connection pool size is 100, all I want to use is 4, should be plenty. But it still fails.

I have also tried to create new DbContexts inside the `GetData` method, but it still fails. If I remember correctly (can't test now), I got

> Underlying connection failed to open

What possibilities there are to make this routine go faster?

Comment: Profile and see which methods/lines use the most time.

Comment: sql-server has a property which governs the maximum number of queries which run in parallel. Check this along with your server load to determine the maximum number parallel queries you can run before sql-server starts to queue these up. sql-server will ultimately prove to be your bottleneck.

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL and results in hard to read queries for complex scenarios. Parallelism will NOT improve the performance of a bad query - it will actually degrade it, often severely due to blocking. Moreover, SQL performance depends on having the proper *indexes*. The only realistic solution is to write the SQL statement you want (probably create a view) and create proper indexes on the underlying tables. SQL Server even has an analyzer to suggest indexes for specific queries or workloads

Comment: @Mark SQL Server doesn't queue queries, nor does it limit the number of concurrent queries *unless you use the resource governor found in the Enterprise edition*. Query performance is affected by bad or missing indexes, not by the parallelization settings

Comment: This question can easily be closed as a duplicate. Use SQL Profiler to capture the SQL statements executed, to see what you are actually sending to the database. Check the execution plans of the queries and fix those that are inefficient by rewriting your LINQ. Once you fix your queries, the next step is to capture another trace using SQL Profiler and pass it to the Database Tuning Advisor to suggest indexes.

Comment: Issue is with loop. Try to rewrite your code taking data from database all in one step, not in each loop iteration.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry I forgot the MAXDOP is to do with processors on a particular query. There is a limit however where SQL server starts to queue up queries if you run sp_who2 you can see they are blocked by the straw that broke the camels back.

Comment: @Mark that's not how SQL Server works. What you see are *not* queued queries, nor are any straws (ie one more query) involved. These are *live* queries that are *blocked* by the locks acquired by other queries. You can have blocking and waits even with 2 queries if you aren't careful, eg updating an entire table while trying to read all of it from another query. The kind and extent of locks depends on the queries and the existence or lack of indexes - if SQL Server can't determine which rows to lock for update, it locks the entire table. The isolation mode also affects whether blocking occurs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand Isolation levels and lock escalations. This is not the blocking I was taking about however it could be in effect in the op's queries. The settings I was getting confused with was max worker threads https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187024

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before going in parallel, it is worth to optimize query itself. Here are some suggestions that might improve your times:

1) Use `Key` when working with `GroupBy`. This might solve issue of complex & nested SQL query as in that way you instruct Linq to use the same keys defined in `GROUP BY` and not to create sub-select.

```
        var confDiscSizePerConfiguration = configurationBuilds
            .GroupBy(c => new { ConfigurationId = c.configuration_id, ConfigurationPath = c.configuration_path})
            .Where(c => (c.Sum(z => z.artifact_dir_size) > maxDiscAllocationPerConfiguration))
            .Select(groupedBuilds =>
                new
                {
                    configurationId = groupedBuilds.Key.ConfigurationId,
                    configurationPath = groupedBuilds.Key.ConfigurationPath,
                    Total = groupedBuilds.Sum(c => c.artifact_dir_size),
                    Average = groupedBuilds.Average(c => c.artifact_dir_size)
                })
            .ToList();
```

2) It seems that you  are bitten by N+1 problem. In simple words - you execute one SQL query to get all configurations and N another ones to get build information. In total that would be ~8k small queries where 2 bigger queries would suffice. If used memory is not a constraint, fetch all build data in memory and optimize for fast lookup using `ToLookup`.

```
var allBuilds = ctx.Builds.ToLookup(x=>x.configuration_id);
```

Later you can lookup builds by:

```
var configurationBuilds = allBuilds[configuration.configuration_id].OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
```

3) You are doing `OrderBy` on `configurationBuilds` multiple times. Filtering does not affect record order, so you can safely remove extra calls to `OrderBy`:

```
...
configurationBuilds = configurationBuilds.Where(x => x.build_date > buildLastCleanupDate);
...
configurationBuilds = configurationBuilds.Take(buildLastCleanupCount);
...
```

4) There is no point to do `GroupBy` as builds are already filtered for a single configuration.

***UPDATE:***

I took it one step further and created code that would retrieve same results as your provided code with a single request. It should be more performant and use less memory.

```
private void CalculateExtendedDiskUsage()
{
    using (var ctx = new LocalEntities())
    {
        var ruleResult = ctx.Configurations
            .Where(x => x.build_cleanup_count != null && 
                (
                    (x.build_cleanup_type == "ReserveBuildsByDays" && ctx.Builds.Where(y => y.configuration_id == x.configuration_id).Where(y => y.build_date > buildLastCleanupDate).Sum(y => y.artifact_dir_size) > maxDiscAllocationPerConfiguration) ||
                    (x.build_cleanup_type == "ReserveBuildsByCount" && ctx.Builds.Where(y => y.configuration_id == x.configuration_id).OrderByDescending(y => y.build_date).Take(buildCleanupCount).Sum(y => y.artifact_dir_size) > maxDiscAllocationPerConfiguration)
                )
            )
            .Select(x => new Notification
            {
                ConfigurationId = x.configuration_id,
                ConfigrationPath = x.configuration_path
                CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                RuleType = (int)RulesEnum.TooMuchDisc,
            })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a new context every parallel.foreach of you going to go that route.  But u need to write a query that gets all the needed data in one trip.  To speed up ef u can also disable change tracking or proxies on the context when ur reading data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of places for optimizations...

There are places where you should put .ToArray() to avoid asking multiple time to server...

I did a lot of refactor, but I'm unable to check, due lack of more information.

Maybe this can lead you to a better solution...

private void CalculateExtendedDiskUsage(IEnumerable allConfigurations)
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

```
        using (var ctx = new LocalEntities())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Context: " + sw.Elapsed);

            var allBuilds = ctx.Builds;
            var ruleResult = GetRulesResult(sw, allConfigurations, allBuilds); // Clean Code!!!

            // find owners and insert...
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Notification> GetRulesResult(Stopwatch sw, IEnumerable<Configuration> allConfigurations, ICollection<Configuration> allBuilds)
    {
        // Lets take only confs that have been updated within last 7 days
        var ruleResult = allConfigurations
            .AsParallel() // Check if you really need this right here...
            .Where(IsConfigElegible) // Clean Code!!!
            .SelectMany(x => CreateNotifications(sw, allBuilds, x))
            .ToArray();

        Debug.WriteLine("Finished loop: " + sw.Elapsed);

        return ruleResult;
    }
    private static bool IsConfigElegible(Configuration x)
    {
        return x.artifact_cleanup_type != null &&
               x.build_cleanup_type != null &&
               x.updated_date > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7);
    }
    private static IEnumerable<Notification> CreateNotifications(Stopwatch sw, IEnumerable<Configuration> allBuilds, Configuration configuration)
    {
        // all builds for current configuration
        var configurationBuilds = allBuilds
            .Where(x => x.configuration_id == configuration.configuration_id);
        // .OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date); <<< You should order only when needed (most at the end)

        Debug.WriteLine("Filter conf builds: " + sw.Elapsed);

        configurationBuilds = BuildCleanup(configuration, configurationBuilds);    // Clean Code!!!
        configurationBuilds = ArtifactCleanup(configuration, configurationBuilds); // Clean Code!!!
        Debug.WriteLine("Done cleanup: " + sw.Elapsed);

        const int maxDiscAllocationPerConfiguration = 1000000000; // 1GB
        // Sum all disc usage per configuration
        var confDiscSizePerConfiguration = configurationBuilds
            .OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date) // I think that you can put this even later (or not to have anyway)
            .GroupBy(c => c.configuration_id) // No need to create a new object, just use the property
            .Where(c => (c.Sum(z => z.artifact_dir_size) > maxDiscAllocationPerConfiguration))
            .Select(CreateSumPerConfiguration);
        Debug.WriteLine("Done db query: " + sw.Elapsed);

        // Extracting to variable to be able to return it as function result
        var notifications = confDiscSizePerConfiguration
            .Select(CreateNotification);

        return notifications;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Configuration> BuildCleanup(Configuration configuration, IEnumerable<Configuration> builds)
    {
        // Since I don't know which builds/artifacts have been cleaned up, calculate it manually
        if (configuration.build_cleanup_count == null) return builds;

        const int buildCleanupCount = 30; // Why 'string' if you always need as integer?
        builds = GetDiscartBelow(configuration, buildCleanupCount, builds); // Clean Code (almost)
        builds = GetDiscartAbove(configuration, buildCleanupCount, builds); // Clean Code (almost)

        return builds;
    }
    private static IEnumerable<Configuration> ArtifactCleanup(Configuration configuration, IEnumerable<Configuration> configurationBuilds)
    {
        if (configuration.artifact_cleanup_count != null)
        {
            // skipped, similar to previous block
        }

        return configurationBuilds;
    }
    private static SumPerConfiguration CreateSumPerConfiguration(IGrouping<object, Configuration> groupedBuilds)
    {
        var configuration = groupedBuilds.First();

        return new SumPerConfiguration
        {
            configurationId = configuration.configuration_id,
            configurationPath = configuration.configuration_path,
            Total = groupedBuilds.Sum(c => c.artifact_dir_size),
            Average = groupedBuilds.Average(c => c.artifact_dir_size)
        };
    }
    private static IEnumerable<Configuration> GetDiscartBelow(Configuration configuration,
        int buildCleanupCount,
        IEnumerable<Configuration> configurationBuilds)
    {
        if (!configuration.build_cleanup_type.Equals("ReserveBuildsByDays"))
            return configurationBuilds;

        var buildLastCleanupDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-buildCleanupCount);
        var result = configurationBuilds
            .Where(x => x.build_date > buildLastCleanupDate);

        return result;
    }
    private static IEnumerable<Configuration> GetDiscartAbove(Configuration configuration,
        int buildLastCleanupCount,
        IEnumerable<Configuration> configurationBuilds)
    {
        if (!configuration.build_cleanup_type.Equals("ReserveBuildsByCount"))
            return configurationBuilds;

        var result = configurationBuilds
            .Take(buildLastCleanupCount);

        return result;
    }

    private static Notification CreateNotification(SumPerConfiguration iter)
    {
        return new Notification
        {
            ConfigurationId = iter.configurationId,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            RuleType = (int)RulesEnum.TooMuchDisc,
            ConfigrationPath = iter.configurationPath
        };
    }
}

internal class SumPerConfiguration {
    public object configurationId { get; set; }   //
    public object configurationPath { get; set; } // I did use 'object' cause I don't know your type data
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public double Average { get; set; }
}
```